# Batch file to let user select file in a folder then rename it

Tags: batch-file

My objective of this batch file is

1. list the DAT files in the current folder (excuding MODDAT.DAT)
2. Let the user select DAT file
3. Rename the chosen DAT file in Step 2 to MODDAT.DAT

Currently I'm stuck in Step 2 and hope someone can help.

```
@echo off
set DIR=%CD%

cd %DIR%

set count=0
set "choice_options="

FOR %%f in (*.DAT) DO ( 
   (Echo "%%f" | FIND /I "MODDAT" 1>NUL) || (
    REM List out menu of the files the user can select
    echo %%f
   )
)

REM user select which file to be renamed as MODDAT.DAT
set /p LoadFile=Select file to load...

copy  "%DIR%\%LoadFile%" "%DIR%\MODDAT.DAT" /Y

exit
```

Comment: In case MODDAT.DAT already exists you can't rename another file to that name, so why not first renaming an eventually existing `MODDAT.DAT` to `MODDAT.bak`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example for you to use/study as required:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "baseDir=%UserProfile%\Desktop"
Set "extFile=.DAT"
Set "dstFile=MODDAT"

For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set item[ 2^>Nul') Do Set "%%A="
Set "i=0"
For %%A In ("%baseDir%\*%extFile%") Do If /I Not "%%~nA"=="%dstFile%" (
    Set /A i+=1 & Set "item[!i!]=%%~nxA")
If %i% Equ 0 GoTo :EOF
If %i% Equ 1 (Set "item[X]=%baseDir%\%item[1]%") Else Call :Menu

Rem Your commands using the selected file, %item[X]%, begin below.
Echo Copy /Y "%item[X]%" "%dstFile%%extFile%"
Pause

GoTo :EOF

:Menu
For /L %%A In (1,1,%i%) Do (Echo %%A. !item[%%A]!)
Set /P "item[X]=Select a file from the above list: "
If Not Defined item[%item[X]%] (ClS & GoTo Menu)
Set "item[X]=%baseDir%\!item[%item[X]%]!"
Exit /B
```

Change `%UserProfile%\Desktop` on line `4` to match the location of your files.
Once you are satisfied that the output is the command you're hoping to run, remove `Echo` from line `14`, *(and optionally line `15`)* to finalise the script.